# How to create a splitviewcontroller fron a view?

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I am new in Xcode. I have viewcontroller with a navigation tabbar with items. I need that one on this menu item calls a splitview with master/detail. Is possible create a splitview in a view and not necessary in appdelegate? In appdelegate I have create one splitview, but if an option on menu.
Is possible to put this code in a the view that i clic the barbutton? The code used is:

```
detallContactesAccions = [[[CrmContactesAccionesDetallVC alloc] init] initWithNibName:@"CrmContactesAccionesDetallVC" bundle:nil];

masterContactesAccions = [[CrmContactesAccionesMasterTVC alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
masterContactesAccions.detailViewController = detallContactesAccions;
masterContactesAccions.navigationItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Acciones",@"");

UINavigationController *navMaster = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterContactesAccions] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navDetail = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detallContactesAccions] autorelease];

splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
//splitViewController.tabBarItem = controller.tabBarItem;

[splitViewController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:300.0] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"]; //Dóna més amplada a l'split view

splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:navMaster, navDetail, nil];
splitViewController.delegate = detallContactesAccions;
```

Comment: As far as I know, the split view controller can't be added in another controller, it has to be the root view controller.

Comment: Hola Emilio. Sabes una alternativa a uisplitviewcontroller? Necesito ejecutar una pantalla uisplit, és decir, maestro/detalle, desde otro viewcontroller y desde un button.